# why it is not possible to use quadratic spline

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, spline, lagrange-interpolation

The following four points are known to lie
on a closed curve in the (x, y)-plane: (−1,0), (−1/2,3), (1/2,−3), (1,0)
and the goal of this question is to fit a piecewise-polynomial approximation of the curve that passes through all four points. [image]

One approach could be to consider two halves separately, that is, define two curves that are both given by the graph of a (polynomial) function of the x-coordinates x0 = −1, x1 = −1/2, x2 = 1/2, and x3 = 1. More precisely, the interpolating polynomial pt(x) for the top half is constructed based on nodes x0, x1 and x3, while the interpolating polynomial pb(x) for the bottom half is based on x0, x2 and x3.

- Show that it is not possible to use quadratic (degree-two) splines for pt(x) and pb(x) such that the combined four-component piecewise-polynomial approximation is a quadratic spline.

I am getting stuck in this question particularly why I cannot use quadratic spline in this term, can someone help me with this question

Comment: At the points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, your two quadratic splines would have to intersect and be tangent.  However, the two quadratics will have unequal derivatives at those two points.  (They'll meet at nondifferentiable "corners" at those two points.)

Comment: how about the second approach which is , define polynomials px(s) and py(s) that pass through the four x- and y-coordinates, respectively. Here s is an arbitrary parameter. Assume that the problem is entirely symmetric, that is, if we define s = 0 at (1, 0) and s = S at (1, 0) after a full closed-loop, then (−1, 0) lies at s = S/2, and if (−1/2, 3) lies at s = s1 then
(1/2, −3) lies at S − s1.  we need to show Show that it is possible to use quadratic splines for px(s) and py(s) such that the combined four-component piecewise-polynomial approximation is a quadratic spline

Comment: how does the second approach differ

Comment: Same answer: try it.  You will find the same problem -- if you specify that the quadratic goes through both points and specify the slope at one of them, the slope at the other is completely determined.  And the forced slopes are not parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show that quadratic splines don't work, is to actually construct them !

Note that both splines go through $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. Hence the splines are of the form $C (1-x^2)$, where $C$ is a constant. Substituting the third point gives $C = 4$ for $pt(x)$ and $C = -4$ for $pb(x)$.

As already pointed out by Eric Towers in the comments, the derivatives of these splines in $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are unequal and hence the tangents intersect.

Comment: how about the second approach which is, define polynomials px(s) and py(s) that pass through the four x- and y-coordinates, respectively. Here s is an arbitrary parameter. Assume that the problem is entirely symmetric, that is, if we define s = 0 at (1, 0) and s = S at (1, 0) after a full closed-loop, then (−1, 0) lies at s = S/2, and if (−1/2, 3) lies at s = s1 then (1/2, −3) lies at S − s1. we need to show Show that it is possible to use quadratic splines for px(s) and py(s) such that the combined four-component piecewise-polynomial approximation is a quadratic spline

Comment: how does the second approach differ